# Can you export "Checkstyle suppressions" from IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

I have been using the suppressions to help me track new issues effectively. Is there a way I can export my "added in my IDE" suppressions so that the rest of the team that uses IntelliJ can use the same ones?  Ideally we would probably git them and pull as needed.

Otherwise, everyone needs to repeat much of the same work on the same code individually.

Comment: I've since noticed most of the time the result of an action taken in the "Warnings" window is a code change like @Suppressions. Those will transfer. Some instead "add to the dictionary", others might set an overall check style option.

As an aside, if these are allowed, is there any way to instead of adding "Maint" to the dictionary when it is triggered by "processMaintMessage" to add the entire thing since the only option, add "Maint" allows stand-alone use of "Maint"